# shared partials error undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, local-variables, renderpartial, partials

I've create a partial (**views/cart/_cart.html.erb**) for my applications shopping cart.  I'm rendering it in only in my **views/layouts/application.html.erb** file.  But when I run it I'm getting a NoMethodError on every page other than the **views/cart/_cart.index.erb**, which I suspect is because it shares the same controller as the partial being rendered.

I've been looking everywhere for an answer & believe it has something to do with how I'm passing variables when rendering the partial, I'll really appreciate it if someone can have a look?

All code can be found here: https://github.com/rossmc/topsnowboards

My code for my partial (**views/cart/_cart.html.erb**) begins:

```
<% @cart = cart%>

<h1>Your Cart</h1>

<% if @cart.empty? %>
    <p>There is nothing in your shopping Cart</p>
<% end %>

<% total = 0 %>

<!-- More code displaying the rest of the cart omitted for brevity
```

The partial is rendered in **views/layouts/application.html.erb** with:

```
<%= render :partial => "/cart/cart", :locals => { :cart => @cart }
```

The **error message** Rails is throwing back at me when I run it is:

```
NoMethodError in Site#home

Showing Server Side/PROJ-Server Side/app/views/cart/_cart.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <h1>Your Cart</h1>
4: 
5: <% if @cart.empty? %>
6:  <p>There is nothing in your shopping Cart</p>
7: <% end %>
8:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of redundancy in the code you mentioned here. `@cart` is an instance variable and it should be available to your partials without any need to pass it as local (depending on where you defined it in the first place of course), so you don't need the first line in your cart partial. Since you render the cart partial in your application layout, it will be rendered in every page that uses this layout (typically, the whole site).

What you need is to make `@cart` variable available to every page (that is, every controller) of your site. Since every controller inherits from your `ApplicationController`, it makes sense to define `@cart` there. Simply add a `before_filter` to `ApplicationController` that defines `@cart`. Skimming quickly through your code, I say this should solve the problem:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :the_cart

  private

  def the_cart
    @cart = session[:cart] || {}
  end

  # the rest of the code ...
end
```

Comment: This works for the partial but throws up another error when I try to sign in with Devise.  The error is: No route matches {:controller=>"devise/products"}.  I'm linking to the sign in page in the application.html.erb with: <%= link_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path  %>

Comment: I've tried changing the link_to to : <%= link_to 'sign in', :controller => "/products", new_user_session_path  %>. But I get more errors

Comment: I guess this should go into a separate question as the main question is already answered and the new issue doesn't seem related to this one. Please don't forget to add the console dump in the new question.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I really appreciate your help. I posted my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/13674840/1814446.

Comment: You were right Ahmad, this was a separate issue all together. I had not defined the link_to in the partial properly to work with devise.  Thanks again for your help.